# I think I know the answer, but it is not what is offered at large. What did Cain do to sin?

Tags: word-study

The body should be provided by the respondents.  I will comment after I see what they have to say.

Comment: Please provide a text you wish to have hermeneutically analyzed. Thank you

Comment: Hi Jon, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how the community works. Please provide a text and a clear question. You may also find it worthwhile to search through previous questions on the text you're looking at, to see if this has already been answered.